# Inject service into NestJS guard

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

We use *ThrottlerGuard* in our **NestJS** application from *@nestjs/throttler package* to rate limit connections and it's implemented like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class RateLimiter extends ThrottlerGuard {
  RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED = 'Rate limit exceeded.';

  async handleRequest(context: ExecutionContext, limit: number, ttl: number) {
    const wsData = context.switchToWs().getData();
    const metadata: MetadataObject = wsData.internalRepr;
    const clientTokenMetadata = metadata.get(TOKEN_NAME) as MetadataValue[];
    const clientToken = clientTokenMetadata[0].toString();
    const tokensArray = await this.storageService.getRecord(clientToken);

    if (tokensArray.length >= limit) {
      throw new RpcException({
        code: Status.UNAVAILABLE,
        message: this.RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED,
      });
    }

    await this.storageService.addRecord(clientToken, ttl);

    return true;
  }
}
```

Now, I need to inject another service, let's say *ConfigService* with the usage of constructor, but because it is an extended class, I need to call **super();** method which required three more original arguments inherited from ThrottlerGuard, but they are not exported from the package. Is there any other way to make it work besides the method with DI in constructor?

Comment: read the docs: [Property-based injection](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#property-based-injection)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, instead of extending `ThrottleGuard` is injecting it in your constructor and call `canActivate()` in `handleRequest()`. Benefit when not extending you don'

I haven't tested this but you can try the following:

```js
import {ExecutionContext, Injectable} from "@nestjs/common";
import {ConfigService} from "@nestjs/config";
import {InjectThrottlerStorage, ThrottlerGuard, ThrottlerStorage} from '@nestjs/throttler'

@Injectable()
export class RateLimiter {

  constructor(
        private throttle: ThrottlerGuard,
        private configService: ConfigService,
        @InjectThrottlerStorage() private storage: ThrottlerStorage) {
  }

  async handleRequest(context: ExecutionContext, limit: number, ttl: number) {
    // TODO something with ConfigService
    return this.throttle.canActivate(context);
  }
}
```

[ThrottleGuard source code](https://github.com/nestjs/throttler/blob/58fc076a603256bdaf1341854a3d40ea40e8e608/src/throttler.guard.ts)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using ThrottlerGuard's storageService which is protected and unavailable if instantiated this way. I edited my question with more code to give a whole guard code overview.

Comment: @PrzemekWit Updated my answer. I checked the source of ThrottleGuard and it seems you can inject ThrottlerStorage. Do you just need access to ThrottlerStorage, because I noticed you didn't use the `canActivate()` method of `ThrottlerGuard's`

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed I needed only ThrottlerStorage. Works like a charm now!